# Email Management System

Tags: email, system

I want to build a Email Management System for our call center. Is there a open source out there that I can? My dev environment is C# and SQL 2005.

Thanks

Tony

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about receiving emails from customers and turning them into tickets. Check out [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems) and look at the Email Integration field.